# Can I use Windows XP for Windows Azure development

Tags: windows, windows-xp, for-loop, azure

I have got the Windows Azure Platform account. 
Fot he development with Windows Azure, can I use computer with Windows XP Professional.
If not what environment should i set to start working with Windows Azure, and migrating existing web projects to Windows Azure.

Regards.
Pravin.

Comment: Have you checked this link http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazure/thread/ad40d420-9bb6-452d-b84c-9928349ab2db/

Answer (score 2):

Since azure uses Windows Server 2008 SP2/R2 as it's core OS, you will need at least Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 to come close to mimicking the environment in Azure. If you are in a situation where you cannot upgrade your OS then you should look at utilizing a VM for development/testing purposes.

To answer your question, **yes** you can hack together a solution, is it pretty, **no**. Would I do it, **no way**. I also find that I like Windows 7 a lot better than XP or Vista, but I am also work for the man so I am jaded.